# concatMap variable amount of promises and pipe results as parameter for the next promise

Tags: javascript, promise, rxjs, reactive-programming, rxjs5

I have a variable amount of promises and I want to execute them in sequence with the result of the previous promise as the parameter of the next one. Currently I managed to concat them in order to execute them in sequence:

```
const promises = [p1, p2, p3, p4, ....];
const source$ = promises.map(p => Rx.Observable.defer(p));
const combination$ = Rx.Observable.concat(...source$);
combination.subscribe((x) => console.log(x));
```

But how can I now manage to pipe the parameters into each promise? I read that I could use concatMap. something like that:

```
Observable.from(p1).concatMap(res => p2(res)).concatMap(res => p3(res))
```

I think I need to somehow always return a new Observable inside concatMap. And also how to chain concatMaps if a number of promises should be variable?

Can someone please point me in the right direction? I am new to the whole reactive programming thing, but for the parts I already understand, it is quite awesome!

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok guys I finally have the result I intended to have

```
const promises = [
  (i=0) => Promise.resolve(i+2), 
  (i=2) => Promise.resolve(i+4), 
  (i=2) => Promise.resolve(i+8)
];

const initial$ = Rx.Observable.from(promises[0]());

promises.reduce((o, p) => o.concatMap(p), initial$)
.subscribe(console.log);
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you could use the [`expand()`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-expand) operator that recursively projects a value emitted from an inner Observable.

For example here I have an array of Observables and I want to add the value accumulated with the current value:

```
const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5].map(v => Observable.of(v));

Observable.of(arr)
    .concatMap(arr => {
        return Observable
            .concat(arr[0]) // get the first item
            .expand((prev, i) => {
                i = i + 1; // We skipped the first Observable in `arr`
                if (i ===  arr.length) {
                    return Observable.empty();
                } else {
                    return arr[i].map(result => prev + result)
                }
            });
    })
    .subscribe(console.log);
```

This prints:

```
1
3
6
10
15
```

Or you can get only the last value if you use `takeLast(1)`:

```
return Observable
    .concat(arr[0])
    .expand((prev, i) => {
        ...
    })
    .takeLast(1);
```

Or there's even easier solution using [`mergeScan`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-mergeScan), however I don't think it's easy to understand:

```
Observable.of(arr)
    .concatAll()
    .mergeScan((acc, observable) => {
        return observable.map(result => result + acc);
    }, 0)
    .subscribe(console.log);
```

The result is the same as in the previous example.

Comment: thank you for your response. I adapted your answer to my needs, but it throws an error (arr[i] is not a function) http://jsbin.com/vocomebini/edit?js,console

Comment: @vacetahanna You're turning each function in `arr` into an Observable with `.map(v => Rx.Observable.defer(v));` that's why it throws the error. When you call `arr[i](prev)` `arr[i]` is not an array, it's an Observable.

Comment: ah ok, but when I try to use .of or .from, then it won't work either. I thought that I could hold the execution of the promises until an explicit call.

Comment: If you wrap them with `Observable.defer` then they'll be created after you subscribe to each one of them.